# Why is the band structure of a supercell more dense than for simple cell?

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, periodic-system

In order to do DFT calculations of metallic alloys, the start point is a supercell, whose atoms are changed to match the desired stoichiometry. Gold and Silver, for example, both have FCC structure. In Quantum-ESPRESSO, we can both tell to the code the *Bravais lattice* (*ibrav* parameter) and specify only one atom position ( $(0,0,0)$ for an FCC cell ), or use a cubic lattice indicating four atoms positions ( $(0,0,0)a$, $(0,0.25,0.25)a$, $(0.25,0,0.25)a$, and $(0,0.25,0.25)a$, in terms of the lattice parameter $a$). In theory, the responses should be the same, and the GND energies are retrieved to be equal. However, the band structure for the four-atoms cell is way denser than the single-atom cell. Why does this occur?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

What you are referring to is called *band folding*.  Remember we are plotting the band structure in the reciprocal space. As  the  size  of  the  cell  in real space increases (eg: when you make a super cell), the first Brillouin zone in reciprocal space  shrinks  and  more  lines  populate  the  band  structure resulting from folding back of lines at the boundaries.

[image]

*The figure$^1$ illustrates band folding in the super cell calculations: (a) band structure of a 2D one-band first- neighbor tight-binding model, (b) the same obtained from a 4x4 super-cell calculation, and (c) the same obtained from a 16x16 super-cell calculation. Panel (d) shows the DOS*

Another figure$^2$ to visualize band folding in 1D
[image]

**There are many tools available to *unfold* the band structure.** Here I list a few

- [BandUP](https://github.com/band-unfolding/bandup): Band Unfolding code for Plane-wave based calculations available for VASP, Quantum Espresso, ABINIT and CASTEP
- [pyPROCAR](https://romerogroup.github.io/pyprocar/unfold.html) offers a utility to unfold bands for VASP
- [Band unfolding made simple](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1361-648X/ab6e8e)$^3$ by May et. al implementation for SIESTA.
- [unfold-x](https://bitbucket.org/bonfus/unfold-x/src/master/) Tool to unfold the band structure of a supercell DFT simulation to a larger Brillouin zone based on QuantumESPRESSO

**References:**

1. Ku, Wei, Tom Berlijn, and Chi-Cheng Lee. "Unfolding first-principles band structures." Physical review letters 104.21 (2010): 216401.
2. Yang, Shuo-Ying, et al. "Symmetry demanded topological nodal-line materials." Advances in Physics: X 3.1 (2018): 1414631.
3. Mayo, Sara G., Felix Yndurain, and Jose M. Soler. "Band unfolding made simple." Journal of Physics: Condensed Matter 32.20 (2020): 205902.

Comment: This is a great answer. Can we send it to the wiki?

Comment: That's best explanation I even seen recently for this band structure folding. Thanks.